# Importing picamera2 works in CLI bot in Thonny IDE

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, picamera, thonny

I have successfully installed picamera2 using this [tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/using-the-picamera2-library-with-tensorflow-lite/) and I am able to run a script just fine from CLI. The script:

```
from picamera2.picamera2 import *
from time import sleep

picam2 = Picamera2()

picam2.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)

config = picam2.preview_configuration()
picam2.configure(config)

picam2.start()
sleep(5)
```

And I run it in terminal `python script_name.py` and it works as it should. But when I run it in Thonny IDE the script returns:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'picamera2'

To my knowledge I have set the default interpreter in Thonny `\usr\bin\python3` and tried also with `\usr\bin\python3.9` and `\usr\bin\python` - they all seem to point to python version 3.9.2 - which is also the version displayed in terminal when running `python -V` or `python3 -V`. What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install python3-picamera2
```